# How to solve a linear system of equations with 2D matrices on the RHS

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this problem:

[image: Problem to solve]

I am trying to declare a matrix of matrices for the right hand side (RHS), but I do not know how do it. I am trying this:

```
MatrizResultados = [[1, 3; -1, 2]; [0, 4; 1, -1]; [2, 1; -1, 1]]
```

But the result is all one matrix, like so:

```
MatrizResultados =

 1     3
-1     2
 0     4
 1    -1
 2     1
-1     1
```

**How can I store these as separate matrices, within one matrix, to solve the above problem?**

Here is my current Matlab code, to try and solve this question:

```
syms X Y Z;

MatrizCoeficientes = [-1, 1, 2; -1, 2, 3; 1, 4, 2];
MatrizVariables = [X; Y; Z];
MatrizResultados = [[1, 3; -1, 2]; [0, 4; 1, -1]; [2, 1; -1, 1]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbolic math toolbox is overkill for this.

This is 4 separate systems of equations, since addition is linear i.e. there is no cross over in matrix elements. You have, for example

```
- x(1,1) + y(1,1) + 2*z(1,1) = 1
- x(1,1) + 2*y(1,1) + 3*z(1,1) = 0
  x(1,1) + 4*y(1,1) + 2*z(1,1) = 2
```

This can be solved using the `mldivide` (`\`) operator, from a matrix of coefficients. This can be constructed like so:

```
% Coefficients of all 4 systems
coefs = [-1 1 2; -1 2 3; 1 4 2];
% RHS of the equation, stored with each eqn in a row, each element in a column
solns = [ [1; 0; 2], [-1; 1; -1], [3; 4; 1], [2; -1; 1] ];

% set up output array
xyz = zeros(3, 4);
% Loop through solving the system
for ii = 1:4
    % Use mldivide (\) to get solution to system
    xyz(:,ii) = coefs\solns(:,ii);
end
```

Result:

```
% xyz is a 3x4 matrix, rows are [x;y;z], 
% columns correspond to elements of RHS matrices as detailed below
xyz(:,1) % >> [-10   7  -8], solution for position (1,1)
xyz(:,2) % >> [ 15 -10  12], solution for position (2,1)
xyz(:,3) % >> [ -1   0   1], solution for position (1,2)
xyz(:,4) % >> [-23  15 -18], solution for position (2,2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have read all code, You have helped me a lot. I about 2.5 hours I will go home again and I will try your code, and I will inform you. If it's not too much trouble, could you comment a bit more on the code? is that I am new to MatLab and I still do not know very well what exactly each part does (like ':' in the loops, what exactly does' \ ', what does' RHS' mean, 'ii = 1: 4', 'xyz ( :, n) '... Again, thank you so much, :)

Comment: Here are the documentation links, read for yourself: `:` is the [colon operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) for getting all elements in a row/column.  `\ `  is [mldivide](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) as stated in my answer. RHS means "Right hand side", and is simply a common mathematical abbreviation meaning the right hand side of the equals sign. `ii = 1:4` is the [for loop](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) variable. `xyz(:, n)` is indexing the nth column of the matrix `xyz`, again see the colon operator.

Comment: I have already seen the documentation and I have tried it. I have no words to thank you ... Thank you very much, my friend, I am very grateful.